# Регистрация и аутентификация в андроид приложении

Tags: android

Прошу совета в следующем вопросе. Нужно реализовать регистрацию и авторизацию в андроид приложении. Планирую делать REST на PHP. Вижу все это в следующем виде:

1. Пользователь регистрируется, присылая нам логин и пароль. Записываем его в базу и генерируем уникальный токен для авторизация без логина и пароля.
2. Получаем токен в андроид приложении и сохраняем его в SharedPreferences.
3. Для последующего общения с сервером используем токен для идентификации пользователя.

В случае, если пользователь нажмет в приложении "Выйти", удаляем токен из приложения и на сервере. При повторной авторизации сгенерируем новый токен и сохраним его в телефоне (для последующей идентификации на сервере).

При этом токены не будут иметь срока годности. То есть токен будет действителен до тех пор, пока пользователь не выйдет из приложения (или повторно не авторизируется).

Хотелось бы услышать мнения по поводу такой схемы. Может есть более изящные (безопасные) способы реализовать подобную задачу?

Answer (score 1):

> Хотелось бы услышать мнения по поводу такой схемы. Может есть более
>   изящные (безопасные) способы реализовать подобную задачу?

Здесь не самое подходящие место для обменивания мнениями.

По сути вопроса:
хорошо бы, чтобы токен имел срок годности, т.к. теряется тогда безопасность.

Ну и неплохо бы два токена: access token & refresh token.

[Тут](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens) можно найти больше инфы про токены и их применение.